# iterate for each element of variable, got TypeError

Tags: javascript

I would like to do something for each element in `my_var`:

```
// get selected rows of DataTable
let table_data = dtMember.rows({ selected: true }).data();
const COL_INDEX = 4 ; // column index of the column to count
let my_var = table_data.reduce(function (col_to_count, currentValue) {
    if (currentValue[COL_INDEX] in kulturen) {
        col_to_count[currentValue[COL_INDEX]]++;
    }
    else {
        col_to_count[currentValue[COL_INDEX]] = 1;
    }
    return col_to_count;                            
}, {});
```

I tried:

```
for (const element of my_var) {
    console.log(element);
}
```

But getting the

> TypeError: my_var is not eterable

I tried also `my_var.entries()` and `my_var.keys()` which are suggested on the help page of firefox but let to `is not a function`

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` for Objects. `of` is for iterating over Arrays.

```
for (const key in my_var) {
  console.log(key, my_var[key])
}
```